# Tensorflow - What does ops constructors mean?

Tags: python, c++, constructor, machine-learning, tensorflow

In this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/basic_usage.html#basic-usage) under the building the graph heading there's a line that says

> "The ops constructors in the Python library return objects that stand for the output of the constructed ops. You can pass these to other ops constructors to use as inputs."

What does the word **constructor** mean? Is it in the context of Object oriented programming or is it in the context of assembling the graph?

Comment: Does it means, tf.Constant is a constructor?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually something in between. "Ops constructor" refers to functions creating new instances of objects being Ops. For example `tf.constant` constructs a new op, but actualy returns a reference to Tensor being a result of this operation, namely instance of `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`, but it is not a constructor in the OOP sense.

In particular things that have actual logic, like `tf.add` will create both `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation` (to perform addition) and `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` (to store the result of the operation), and only tensor will be returned (this is what cited part of documentation tries to explain).

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.add(tf.constant(1), tf.constant(2))

for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
  print op

print tensor
```

will result in

```
name: "Const"
op: "Const"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
attr {
  key: "value"
  value {
    tensor {
      dtype: DT_INT32
      tensor_shape {
      }
      int_val: 1
    }
  }
}

name: "Const_1"
op: "Const"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
attr {
  key: "value"
  value {
    tensor {
      dtype: DT_INT32
      tensor_shape {
      }
      int_val: 2
    }
  }
}

name: "Add"
op: "Add"
input: "Const"
input: "Const_1"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}


Tensor("Add:0", shape=TensorShape([]), dtype=int32)
```

Three ops have been created "in background", while you still operate on Tensor level (which has been returned by `tf.add`). It's name (created by default) suggests that it is a tensor produced by `Add` operation.

#### Update

A simple python-based example might be more usefull, so TF does something like this:

```
class B:

  def __init__(self):
    print 'Constructor of class B is called'
    pass

class A:

  def __init__(self):
    print 'Constructor of class A is called'
    self.b = B()

def create_something():
  print 'Function is called'
  a = A()
  b = a.b
  print 'Function is ready to return'
  return b

print create_something()
```

as you can see `create_something` is not a constructor, it calls a constructors of some classes and returns some instance, but itself is not constructor (nor initializer) in the OOP sense. It is more like a factory design paradim.

Comment: So I am wrong if I say, tf.Constant is a constructor as in OOP?

Comment: Yes, this is wrong. This is not a constructor in OOP sense. It calls a few constructors, but itself is not an OOP constructor.

Comment: Okay, Could you please explain your answer in a bit more detail? Some part of your answer went over my head.

Comment: The part that I cannot understand is, how this constructor is different from OOP constructor? Did you mean, like add constructor calls three constructors two constants and one add constructor?

Comment: I created a python-only example in my code to illustrate, hope it helps. The main difference is that it is **a regular function**, something among the lines of **factory design paradigm**, constructor in OOP is assigned to a particular class. Here it is not, it does more logic than that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Could you provide me a link where I can read more about it?

Comment: I am afraid that you will have to read through the code / documentation itself. I do not know any resource of this kind for TF, my answer is based on going through the source code.